# beamer 2x2 fields with graphics and text blocks

Tags: beamer

i have a sample code with which i'm trying to use the whole space of the slide for 1 image plus a text block (2 x 1 invisible table e.g.) or 2 images plus 2 text blocks (2 x 2). But for the latter i'm not able to make text blocks centered en their "cells". At the bottom i put an image of what i want. I did it in loimpress.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./} {../../items/} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]
\begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apple.png}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \center\huge apple \\
  pomme
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c]
\begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{banana.png}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apple.png}

  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \center\huge banana \\
  banane \\
  apple \\
  pomme
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW: I have never seen so long apples or so round bananas. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities to achieve what you want, including tikz. The above answers so far suffer a bit from limited control of the exact position. My favorite approach is to use a `\textblock` for the "rows" and then use a `columns` environment inside the textblock. Most of the time this seems to correspond to the way how slide content is used/composed (at least for me...).

Here is an example how you could achieve this:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./} {../../items/} }

% textpos allows to arbitrary position TeX code, e.g., by 
% \begin{textblock}{1}(0., -0.08) Some text \end{textblock}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos}  % delete "showboxes" to remove the outline of the text boxes
\TPGrid{1}{1} % defines the units


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[c]
        % ====================================================================================================
        % ======= Define the upper row with image on the left and text on the right.                     =====
        % ====================================================================================================
        \begin{textblock*}{0.9\pagewidth}(0.05\pagewidth, 0.01\pageheight)  % {size}(hpos, vpos)
            \begin{columns}
                % ------ the left "box" with the image ------------------
                \column{0.45\textwidth}
                    \color{blue}\fbox{\color{black} %  draw the blue box on the left        
                  % The minipage takes all the horizontal space of the column;
                  % the height (0.42\textwidth) can be changed and defines the height of the row
                        \begin{minipage}[c][0.42\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
                            \centering
                            \includegraphics[width=0.25\pagewidth]{apple}
                        \end{minipage}
                    }
                % -------- the right "box" with the text ----------------
                \column{0.45\textwidth}
                    \color{red}\fbox{\color{black}%  draw the red box on the right
                        \begin{minipage}[c][0.42\textheight][c]{0.95\textwidth}
                            \centering\huge apple\\
                            pomme 
                        \end{minipage}
                    }
            \end{columns}               
        \end{textblock*}        
        % ====================================================================================================
        
        
        % ====================================================================================================
        % ======= Define the lower row with image on the left and text on the right.                    ======
        % ======= This is independent of the upper "row" -- just specify the offset (vpos) of textblock ======
        % ====================================================================================================
        \begin{textblock*}{0.9\pagewidth}(0.05\pagewidth, 0.5\pageheight)  % {size}(hpos, vpos)
            \begin{columns}
                % ------ the left "box" with the image ------------------
                \column{0.45\textwidth} % width of the green box
                \color{green}\fbox{\color{black} %  draw the green box on the left      
                    \begin{minipage}[c][0.42\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
                        \centering
                        \includegraphics[width=0.25\pagewidth]{banana}
                    \end{minipage}
                }
                % -------- the right "box" with the text ----------------
                \column{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \color{cyan}\fbox{\color{black}%  draw the cyan box on the right
                    \begin{minipage}[c][0.42\textheight][c]{0.95\textwidth}
                        \centering\huge banana\\
                        banane\\
                        banana
                    \end{minipage}
                }
            \end{columns}               
        \end{textblock*}    
        % ====================================================================================================
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I added colored boxes to show which object is which (black: textblock, colored: minipages within colum environments): you can remove the boxes by deleting "showboxes" in the respective usepackage command and by deleting the lines containing `fbox` (including the closing "}").

The arguments of the textblock environment allow absolute positioning of content on the frame, the columns environment do what they do best ...

Finally, here's a screenshot: [image: screenshot].

Last but not least, from my code it should be clear that you can also do this using *only* textblocks, not using the colums environment at all. But that might be a matter of taste ;)

I hope that this is useful for someone!

Answer (score 2):

You can organize images and belonging text with table.

**Edit:** Regarding to your comment (after 20 days!) now images height are defined by `height=<desired vale>` and text is also horizontali centered by changing type of column to `C` and `X[c, font=\huge]`. BTW those requirements are not clear (at least to me) from question. Hopefully now both examples are what you after.

For example:

- with `tabularx` and `adjustbox` packages:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
\graphicspath{ {./} {../../items/} }
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C@{\qquad\qquad}>{\huge}C}
\includegraphics[height=33mm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}
    &   I'm a duck who love bananas \\
    \addlinespace
\includegraphics[height=33mm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}
    &   I'm a duck who love apples \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- by use of the `tabularray` and `adjustbox` packages:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
\graphicspath{ {./} {../../items/} }
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]
\adjustboxset{{height=33mm, valign=m}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[c] X[c, font=\huge]},
                 measure = vbox
                 }
\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
    &   I'm a duck who love bananas \\
\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
    &   I'm a duck who love apples \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The height of the rows is not controlled. The text is not centered, and '\\' will add a new row instead of a newline.

Comment: Images and text are vertical centered,  height of images is implicite controlled by width of images. However, I can do this explicit. See edited answer.

Comment: the fact that i wanted centered text on both dimensions was clear enough in my text. I had said "text centered in their cell", which means both V and H. height control was not requested but i made clear that it's a 2x2 table covering the whole space and i illustrated with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Without additional packages, the content could be organized using four `minipages`.

The default behavior of the `minipage` is to center its content vertically. The `\centering` inside does it horizontally.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}  
    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./} {../../items/} }

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[c]
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering\huge apple \\
            pomme
        \end{minipage}
        \vfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering\huge  banana \\
            banane \\
            apple \\
            pomme
        \end{minipage}  
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: here you stacked 4 minipages. As a result i get a stack of minipages, not 2 x 2.

Comment: @user1850133 As I understood your question the only issue was to auto **center* the content (figures or text) in their quarter of the frame.  There are many alternatives to do that.  The minpage is a useful  latex environment, easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, without any other package or structures like tabular or minipage. Just a `columns` environment for any pair image+text will do it.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./} {../../items/} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]
\begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \center\huge apple \\
  pomme
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c]
\begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering\huge banana \\
  banane \\
\end{columns}
\begin{columns}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering\huge 
  apple \\
  pomme
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no control on the height.

Comment: @user1850133 the control of the height is fixed with the height of the figure. `\includegraphics[height=...]{...}`. In my example I've only fixed image width, but you can decide what you prefer.